# regex - find specific string but not when present in certain sentence

Tags: regex

I am not sure if it is possible with one regex line. I want to find sentence with particular string but not when it present in specific sentence.

This is like grep 'word' *file* | grep -iv "particular sentence"

Eg:
Input:

> Hello world foo here
>
> foobar here there
>
> foo with bar
>
> bar with foo now

result should be to find word 'foo' but not when the sentence is 'bar with foo now':
Output:

> Hello world foo here
>
> foobar here there
>
> foo with bar

Is this possible with one line regex pattern?

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
^(?!bar with foo now).*?foo.*$
```

Which says "match a line that isn't "bar with foo now", but has "foo" in it".

However, you'll only get one match per line. So if you had:

> Hello my foo is foo.

That will match, but only once for the entire line (as opposed to twice, once for each `foo`).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It works! Now can I add more than one sentence there. Like if i want to exclude two sentence like one 'bar with foo now' and other 'foobar here there', how can I do that?

Comment: You'd do `(?!bar with foo now|foobar here there)` instead of `(?!bar with foo now)`.

Comment: When I try ^(?!with foo now).*?foo.*$ it doesnt work. So it has to be a complete sentence? Also I have an array of sentences on which this regex not working!

Comment: Well, the regex in the `(?!)` has to be a full sentence, because I've anchored the entire regex with `^` and `$`. Re the regex not working, this could be the regex, or you how are testing the regex (in whichever language it is you are doing) - you'll have to update your original question with the problem array & associated code you're using to test the regex.